# Postgres records not being create but PK is being incremented

Tags: postgresql

I am running a Python script and using pyscopg2 and wxPython extensions to add records to a local PostgreSQL database.  The script runs without error. When I check the table using pgAdmin4 the records aren't there.  When I add a record manually in pgAdmin4 the primary key (a serial type) has skipped ahead exactly the number of records that should have been added  from the Python script.  A separate, but similar, occurrence is the DELETE command is running without error but no records are deleted.  When I run the same command locally all requested records are deleted.   What am I not doing correctly?

I know the connection is open, I got several error messages regarding syntax and have worked those those out.  I have tried running the commands by hardcoding the values rather than the variables.

```
sSQLMessage = ("DELETE FROM plots WHERE mapid = " + mapnum + " AND plotnum = " + plotnum)
    wx.MessageBox(sSQLMessage)
    cur.execute(sSQLMessage)
    sSQLMessage = ("INSERT INTO plots (plotnum, mapid, plotshape, labelpnt, supplypnt, unitspnt) VALUES (" \
             + plotnum + ", " + mapnum + ",  ('( " + polyCoords + " )')  , '" + plotCoords + "' , '" + supplyCoords + "' , '" + unitsCoords + "');")
    wx.MessageBox(sSQLMessage)
    cur.execute(sSQLMessage)
```

Comment: Do you COMMIT the changes?

Comment: I had to look it up, but that was the problem.   This newb Thanks you!!

Comment: Offtopic: Your code is prone to SQL injection. https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/11/preventing-sql-injections/